# Will redirecting expired domains to my website help or attract penalties?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, expired-domains

I am developing a entertainment website and have found more than 4 entertainment domains (expired domains). Domain authority of these domains are 25 or more.

If I will redirect these domain to my site then will this help my site or will penalize website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain authority on expired domains comes mostly from the inbound links to their deep pages.   If you have similar enough content that your domain can satisfy the users that click on those links then you *might* get some SEO benefit from the domain redirect.   To get it, you would have to put appropriate redirects in place.

For example if you find a link to:

```
expireddomain.example.com/blog/the-wonders-of-blue-widgets
```

you could redirect it to your blue widgets page:

```
mysite.example.com/blue-widgets
```

It wouldn't work to:

- Redirect it to `mysite.example.com/blog/the-wonders-of-blue-widgets` and give users a 404 error
- Redirect it to your home page: `mysite.example.com/` which Google would view as a "soft 404" and not give the link any credit
- Redirect it to an unrelated page such as `mysite.example.com/red-filanges` (which wouldn't satisfy visitors).

If the links to the expired domains are spammy or paid, redirecting the expired domains to your site would **hurt** your rankings.   It would be likely that Google would penalize your site.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a great idea, when handled properly.**

You need to to some research about domains first

- Verify that there is not Manual Penalty to this domain (Verify it
  through Google Webmaster Tool )
- Check the back-links of domain if any. It might be victim of Penguin
  2 & 2.1 (You can use ahref.com for example)

Redirecting domains without above verifications could lead you to hell.

Answer (score 1):

Before redirecting those domains to your new domain you need to do some research about those domains first.If any domain is penalized by google then your new website will get penalized too. So first of all you need to Check the back-links of those domains.