# Does Google penalize for redirecting too many expired domain to my site?

Tags: seo, redirects, ranking, penalty, expired-domains

I used to 301 redirect expired domains to my site and now I think I made a mistake. If we redirect more than a single domain to a particular website, will hurt SEO?

Comment: @gael please don't put answers or partial answers into comments.   If you can answer this question, please do so.  Comments are meant for asking for clarification and such.  It is [problematic to have answers in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will redirecting expired domains to my website help or attract penalties?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89836/will-redirecting-expired-domains-to-my-website-help-or-attract-penalties)

Comment: Ya, it helped me..thanks a lot